# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

And I don't know how to fix it.

I have installed MySQL, Apache2, PHP and phpMyAdmin. Then I've changed a few things in the .htaccess file and changed AllowOverride from none to all (not sure where I did this again). That's all I've done with the server. I read people talking about databases, but I've only got 1 DB.

Comment: Check your SQL connection string. In message tells that you didn't provided password, but the 'root' user has it.

Comment: Hey Hayk Manasyan, thanks for the reply. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're attempting to access the database with the root user, without providing the corresponding password.
If you have no idea what the password is, I suggest you attempt to recover it, using [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) procedure.